# C shell script last command not working

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed, csh

I have this C shell (unfortunately C is required) script called `EditFile.script` consisting entirely of 6 different sed commands, all to be applied to one text file.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

1i GameTime!!!!!!\n #append "GameTime!!!!!! at the beginning
s/pionts/points/g #sub typo
s/shot/shoot/g #sub typo
s/the\sthe/the/g #sub double the's with "the"
/^ *$/d #delete all blank lines
$a Game\nOver #append "Game Over" to the end of the file
```

Now the text file is 400+ lines long and I think posting it here (and its desired form) would be a waste of space.

However, when I run `sed -f EditFile.script GameManual` at the cmdline all of the above commands work *except* for the final command. No 
"Game Over" is appended to the end of the file. I believe it has something to do the with preceding "delete all blank lines `/^ *$/d` command- because when I ran the script with it removed, "Game Over" was appended. But I don't see the connection.

Why will the final sed command in the script not show? Also, since this is my first time using a csh script (and c shell), what other additions must I make for the  script to work?

Comment: If these are `sed` commands (executed with `sed -f`), it's not really a "C shell script" and you can remove the `#!/bin/csh -f` (which is just a comment as far as `sed` is concerned). Not sure if it makes a difference, but what (interactive) shell are you running the `sed` command *from*?

Comment: @steeldriver C shell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with C shell - and in fact, as noted in the comments, what you have is a *sed script* (a simple text file of `sed` commands) rather than a shell script, and the `#!/bin/csh -f` shebang is superfluous and will be treated (by sed) as a simple comment.

What you seem to be observing is that `sed` *appears* to not re-evaluate the `$` (last line) address, so that if one of your previous commands happens to delete the last line of the file, then a subsequent attempt to append<sup>1</sup> after that address fails. We can see that with a simple test (using the `bash` shell, for what it's worth) as follows:

```
# delete line 3 then append after $
$ printf 'line %d\n' {1..3} | sed -e '/3/d' -e '$a\new line'
line 1
line 2
```

whereas

```
# append after $ then delete line 3
$ printf 'line %d\n' {1..3} | sed -e '$a\new line' -e '/3/d'
line 1
line 2
new line
```

I find this somewhat surprising but don't know if it's the desired behavior or should be considered a bug.

---

*Note:*

[1] Techically, the `a` command doesn't append, but rather

> Queue[s] the lines of text which follow [ ... ] to be output at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line is read.